# Error message 'unknown member'

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using Monodroid and C#.Net.

I have been getting error message whenever I try to access a method on my web service which reads 'unknown member Invoke' and it occurs on the `object[] results = this.Invoke("MethodName", new object[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your method does not exist...

Comment: The method name there is GetListItems. When I try to invoke the same method through windows application it returns the items. So it not only exits but functioning well.

Comment: @Kimarov: How do you invoke your methode when you do get results?

Comment: This is how I invoke a method from my web service. Service1 serv = new Service1(); serv.Url = "http://localhost/WebServ/Service1.asmx"; var Mylist = serv. GetListItems ();

Comment: Could you please add the code for the GetListItems methode to your post? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Kimarov, you should explain a bit more showing also a bit more code.

I am almost sure the issue here is that there is no method called `MethodName` in your target object and that's why your invokation is failing.

Comment: The Method name stands for the name of the function being invoked